# How to merge three columns(nvarchar,null) into a single column (nvarchar) by keeping space between the each value if value is not null ?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three columns like FirstName, MiddleName, LastName I want merge them all into a single column like FullName by giving space between the Fistname and Middle, Middle and LastName if the values are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddleName,'')  + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName,'') AS FullName
FROM [Table]
```